# How to find position from buttoncollection?

Tags: ios, swift

programmers! :]

Please, help me. I have a collection of buttons

```
@IBOutlet var buttonCollection: [UIButton]!
```

How can I find which one was pressed?

```
@IBAction func pressButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
.....
    for i in 0...array.count - 1 {
        buttonCollection[i].setTitle(String(array[i]), for: .normal)
    }
.....
}
```

I want to setTitle only to those buttons which wasn't pressed.

What else can I use except tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the button reference `sender` with your Buttons array.

```
@IBAction func pressButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        //Compare sender with array
        if sender != buttonCollection[i] {
            buttonCollection[i].setTitle(String(array[i]), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't help and still fill button which was pressed. :[
But still, thanks, I'll play with this.

Comment: @DmytroRyshchuk Is your all button share same action? Also after pressing one button if it press another button then you want to not set title for both the button or one which is pressed currently?

Comment: Yeap, they used the same action. 
Yes, If I pressed that button I want that it doesn't get any of titles.

Comment: I think it's because my logic isn't perfect in app :[[[
P.S. Sorry, I can't mark this message as useful, because I have low reputation.